# MYSQL count the row that is not empty

Tags: mysql

I need to count only those row that is not empty. thanks.

```
SELECT component,count(comp_details) FROM table GROUP BY component
```

Comment: is comp_details nullable?

Answer (score 2):

While you want to count conditionally yet your query does not have any `WHERE` part

```
SELECT component,count(comp_details) 
FROM table 
WHERE IFNULL(component, '') != ''
GROUP BY component
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:Add a where clause based on requirement.

```
SELECT component,count(comp_details) FROM table where comp_details is not null and comp_details != "" GROUP BY component
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `comp_details is not null AND comp_details != ""`?